# How do I get a field for a user from another table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am starting to learn Laravel and I want to understand how can I get data for a specific user from another table using a model? For example, in my code, I want to check if the user has permission to edit a document or not. I can do it with a request, but I want to use the User models so the code looks better and easier.

And so, as a result, I want to get something like this:

```
if(User::permission()->myPermission){}
```

How can I achieve this result? The User model was originally, I want to understand how to change it

Comment: if you need to get the logged in user permission , you can use this :- auth()->user()->permission->myPermission; 
you cant use User::permission , you get user then you get the related permission .

Comment: please post your User model. In there you should have a relation with Permission model